# R: How are factor labels mapped to the correct values in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

*EDIT: Included my reading of the documentation that I am still not clear on*

I'm new to R and playing around with the RStudio pre-loaded `mtcars` `data.frame`. I am converting the `cyl` variable to factors and labeling them. My code is:

```
df <- mtcars
str(df)
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl, labels = c('Four cylinder', 'Six Cylinder', 'Eight Cylinder'))
str(df)
```

Which outputs:

```
> df <- mtcars
> str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
> df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl, labels = c('Four cylinder', 'Six Cylinder', 'Eight Cylinder'))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "Four cylinder",..: 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

**My question is:** How is the `factor` section of code assigning the labels properly (i.e. `'Four cylinder'`, represented as `1` after the transformation, is being correctly assigned the the `4`s in the original `df`). Is it simply applying the labels in ascending order as the default behavior? What if I have a field with, say, 10 unique values that I want to convert to factors. How can I be sure my labels and replacement values are corresponding to the correct original values?

The documentation accessed by `?factor` states:

> levels: an optional vector of the values (as character strings) that x might have taken. The default is the unique set of values taken by as.character(x), sorted into increasing order of x.

This appears to be stating that the labels are to be applied in ascending order by original variable value, but I just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: This link does a fairly good job of explaining how factors work https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/

Comment: That was helpful for understanding the default behavior of `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` but does not answer my question about `factor` and how it applies labels to the intended values

Comment: A colleague sent me [THIS](http://monashbioinformaticsplatform.github.io/2015-09-28-rbioinformatics-intro-r/01-supp-factors.html): I believe it answers the question. I'm going to read it and then answer my own question if that's the proper thing to do?

Comment: The behavior of factors _is_ the reason for the default behavior of `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.  Starting in the eighth paragraph "There’s also a more obscure reason.", the article describes how integers are used to reference, effectively, a look up of the character value in order to save memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It knows in this example, because it converts the numeric values in mtcars$cyl into a character vector `c(4, 6, 8, 6, ...) -> c("4", "6", "8", ...)`, the levels are selected by alphnumerical sorting ('4' then '6', then '8'; since you haven't specified the `levels` in your call to `factor`), then the numeric values stored in `df$cyl` are found by matching the `values` against the `levels`. The labels don't really affect the factor ordering: you could, perversely, match the label "six cylinders" with the level "4".

> as.numeric(factor(c(4, 6, 8, 6, 6, 4)))
>   [1] 1 2 3 2 2 1

Comment: Got it with the alphanumerical sorting - that's what I suspected based on the documentation. Can you clarify how I could match the label "six cylinders" with the level "4" (btw is level the correct word here? or is it value)?

Comment: Here we give the level "4" the label "five cylinders?" and various other perversities: `factor(c(6, 4, 8), labels = c("five cylinders?", "four cylinders?", "three cylinders"))
[1] four cylinders? five cylinders? three cylinders
Levels: five cylinders? four cylinders? three cylinders`

Comment: Ahh, duh. Thanks so much - as a new programmer I know this stuff probably sounds dumb to you but it is incredibly helpful for my understanding.